# Filtering a Table on one sheet from a Searchbox on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm unfortunately new to VBA so forgive the ignorance.
I need to filter a table on one sheet by manually searching numbers & text into a search box on another sheet. I can't seem to get all the way there.  Are there better/simpler options available?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim strFilter As String
strFilter = “ * ” & [C4] & “ * ”
Debug.Print strFilter
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(“Table2”).Range.AutoFilter _
Field:=1, _
Criteria1:=strFilter, _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then the following should help.
First of all, make sure you use " " instead of “ ”, or VBA will just throw errors.

Assuming you're using an ActiveX textbox then you can get the value from it simply by referencing TextBox1.Value as shown below.
If the table is on a different sheet, you should reference the sheet directly instead of using Activesheet. I used Sheet2 in this example.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim strFilter As String

    strFilter = "*" & TextBox1.Value & "*"
    Debug.Print strFilter
    
    Sheet2.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=strFilter, _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```